# Erro ao iniciar Mysql no WSL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Olá,

estou com um problema ao iniciar o Mysql 5.7 no WSL com Ubuntu 18.04.

ao tentar iniciar o serviço com:

`$ sudo service mysql start
$ * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                                                -su: 23: .: Can't open /etc/profile.d/wsl-integration.sh`

O arquivo  wsl-integration.sh é um link para ''

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Oct 24 11:15 wsl-integration.sh -> ''`

Alguém pode me ajudar? pois já pesquisei na NET e parece que ninguém passou por isso..

Answer (score 0):

Esse link simbólico para o wsl-integration.sh parece estar inválido, deveria retornar o caminho original, algo como:

```
ls -l
wsl-integration.sh -> '/root/wsl-integration.sh'
```